# how to return the user to the previous page when a span is clicked

Tags: url, action

When a user clicks a specific button i'd like it to return the user to the previous page visitied.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
<span><a onclick="history.go(-1)" href="#">Text here</a></span>
```

Comment: Mmm.. I'd much rather use something that involves it's href property which would automatically format linking :D

Comment: `<span><a href="javascript:history.back()">Back</a></span>`

Comment: Don't use `href="javascript:..."`. IE behaves strange in this case. See my update answer.

Comment: What about a solution for non-JS browsers?